# How to avoid a MySQL deadlock?

Tags: java, mysql

I have written a program that is running on a server that updates certain informations all the time. Most of the time this is data from external apis. There are no events that I could call. Therefore I have to do this periodically. Here is a pseudocode for this:

```
boolean taskStarted = false;

main() {
  time.schedule(createCustomTask(() -> {
    if (taskStarted) return;
    taskStarted = true;
    // UPDATE ALL DATA
    taskStarted = false;
  }), 0, 5_000L);
}

createCustomTask(Runnable r) {
  return new TimerTask() {
    @Override public void run() {
      if (LocalDateTime.NOW.getSeconds() < 5)
        runnable.run(); 
    }
  };
}
```

I try to request and update the data at the beginning of every minute. This will only be done if the previous loop is completed.

Now this look good but the problem is that this will result in a deadlock if the same table is used by another program or another transaction that tries to access the same table/data at the same time. Usually this is not an issue because you access the table, update it, close the transaction and the table is no longer locked. However in this case this code causes to hold the table in "lock-mode" almost all the time.

#### Why is this a problem?

| userid | allowed |
| --- | --- |
| 4b216de4-b6c6-4ef8-ae34-9395508cd49a | 1 |
| e57cb337-d2a3-4a15-878d-9c3da756a4b1 | 0 |

Lets say we have a table with all userids and if they are allowed to connect to a specific server. Now someone wants to join this server. We have to check if his userid is registered in the database, if not we will insert this userid in the database with an allowed-value of 0 (false). If the user is registered and allowed is 1 (true) this user will be able to connect. We do not want the user to wait minutes until the lock is removed. We want to access/update the data immediately.

A solution would be to store all user data in the local storage and update it every few minutes and use this as a backup if a deadlock occurs. But this is not a great solution. Is there any workaround to avoid this?

When I access the database I expect to access this database but its in lock mode way to long.

Comment: the deadlock would occur if thesame rows are updated, or you made a table lock

Comment: Do you have one (java) server on which all code runs? Or do you have multiple replicas?

Comment: It is running on one server

Comment: In tranitional RDBMS, like MySQL, there is the concept of Isolation Levels (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html) to avoid lock contention.  This would allow each thread in java to access the database with different Isolation levels (albeit this is harder to program).

Alternatively since you have just 1 java application you have the option to managing the locking control in java code to avoid a deadlock.

Is the userid table you talk about the central problem that is locked for long periods? ... I need to know more about the situation to go further on this.

Comment: Locking rows or even a table does not result in deadlock. Deadlock occurs if different transactions lock tables or rows that another transaction needs, which in turn locks tables or rows the first one needs, therefore neither can progress. The situation you describe seems to give raise to lock timeout issues -a transaction has to wait too long to obtain a lock. You have to modify your code to lock as few resources as possible at any given point in time: do not lock tables, just rows, commit as early as possible, use indexes for locking reads and updates and perhaps lock them in a certain order

Comment: Its likely that I found the issue: Multiple threads are accessing the same row. I.e. the user can change the username and there is a thread that updates this username. Another thread is updating whether or not the user is allowed to join. Both use the same transaction and if the Transaction is commited it commits the whole thing. Since its not commited the table is hold in lock mode for this long. There is another application that now also updates this row when the user goes online. This might be the result of the deadlock.